# Why is this SQL statement giving me an invalid column name error?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, parameters

I'm trying to use an SQL select statement to read from a database to validate a login form. The problem I'm having is its telling me its an invalid column name.

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE [username] = @theusername  
AND [password] = @thepassword
```

where @theusername is a parameratized value of "Rymo_18", and the password is, for the sake of argument, "password".

The errors I get are:

Invalid column name 'Rymo_18'.

Invalid column name 'password'

Don't know why I'm getting those errors. I've tried swapping the values around the = sign, tried using values directly (username = "Rymo_18") and all other matters of fiddling to fix it, and I've had no luck. There are no other tables called 'user' within my Database.

EDIT: Here's the code as it appears in the C# I'm using:

```
string user = unametext.Text;
        string pword = pwordtext.Text;

        string connectionstring = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["elmtreeconnect"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection myconnection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);

        myconnection.Open();

        string query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username= @theusername OR email = @theusername) AND password = @thepassword";

        SqlCommand attemptLogin = new SqlCommand(query, myconnection);

        attemptLogin.Parameters.AddWithValue("@theusername", user);
        attemptLogin.Parameters.AddWithValue("@thepassword", pword);

        SqlDataReader rdr = attemptLogin.ExecuteReader();

        if (rdr.HasRows)
        {
            Session["user"] = rdr["username"].ToString();
            Session["id"] = rdr["id"].ToString();
            Session["type"] = rdr["accountType"].ToString();

            Response.Redirect("loginsuccess.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            unametext.Text = "";
            pwordtext.Text = "";

            statusLabel.Text = "Login failed. Please try again, or contact info@elmtree.co.uk for assistance";

        }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You must be concatenating the parameters in not using them as shown in the question. So you are also vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Yeah. Avoid SQL injection by using prepared statements.

Comment: Also, what language are you using?

Comment: That isn't the actual code I'm using. Was using it for sake of demonstration. I'll post up the C# code that I'm using thats producing the same error.

Comment: I'm using C# with MSSQL for the database query

Comment: Aside from the current issue this appears to be problematic as it seems you are storing passwords in clear text. All passwords should be salted and hashed.

Comment: I'll have to post up the rest later. It's giving me an update error at the minute.

Comment: Sean, this is for a university project, everything works over an internal network so we were told not to worry about plaintext passwords, just to protect the database from SQL injection attacks by filtering input.

Comment: I would VERY strongly disagree that passwords are acceptable to be stored in clear text. Considering that most typical people have 2-3 passwords for absolutely everything this is potentially putting all those users at risk. Likely their email passwords and even bank accounts have the same password. It is super easy to protect this information. Doing so is dangerous. Unless of course this is just dummy data for a class project in which case it probably doesn't really matter that much....unless the users are real...then you are right back to the same issue. :)

Comment: yeah, all data is dummy data. The website is uploaded, assessed then removed.

Comment: Update has now been posted.

Comment: Remove SELECT EXISTS

Comment: wrap your or condition in paranthesis `SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username= @theusername OR email = @theusername) AND password = @thepassword`

Comment: no joy. Still getting the same errors.

Comment: Can you run SQL Profiler to see exactly what the query looks like when it's run in SQL Server?

Comment: I'm with Adam. Really looks like what you've posted won't generate the problematic column name error, so see what is actually getting executed. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

```
string query = "select 1 from users where username=@theusername and password=@password";
...
if(rdr.Read()){
...
}
```

`exists` should be used in `if exists(select...)`

Comment: using that, I get an IndexOutOfRangeException on Line 108:                Session["user"] = rdr["username"].ToString();

Comment: `select id, username, accountType from users...`. Select only what you need.

Comment: didn't work. Now getting an Invalid attempt to read when no data is present warning, same one I was getting at the start, along with the column name.

Comment: `if(rdr.Read()){/*do what you need here and not outside*/} rdr.Close();` don't forget to close your reader.

Comment: Check your column  names in the DB. Create query in SSMS and then copy to your code.